# Removing everything after the first " " in a string? (space)

Tags: c#

I am trying to remove everything after the first space in a string, now I have already tried this but it really doesn't work.

What did I try?

```
List<string> lines = new List<string>();

foreach (string textLine in richTextBox1.Lines)
{
    lines.Add(textLine.Substring(0, textLine.IndexOf(" ") + 1));
}

richTextBox1.Text = "";

foreach (string line in lines)
{
    richTextBox1.Text += line + Environment.NewLine;
}
```

String example:

```
some:kind of string   that I want      totrim please.
```

Now.. It SHOULD remove everything after "some:kind", why is it not? It's only trimming the occurance of the character at the end of each line, and only once.

What I am trying to split (proxy list)

```
83.71.175.121:8080  HTTP    NOA Ireland 30% (9) +   11-jul-2017 21:06
188.120.209.97:53281    HTTPS   HIA Czech Republic  70% (14) +  11-jul-2017 21:05
41.87.86.51:3128    HTTP    NOA Nigeria 64% (9) +   11-jul-2017 21:05
187.84.222.153:80   HTTP    ANM Brazil  61% (160) + 11-jul-2017 21:04
36.78.131.82:3128   HTTP    NOA Indonesia   25% (49) +  11-jul-2017 21:02
181.199.202.248:8080    HTTPS   NOA Spain   38% (35) +  11-jul-2017 21:01
180.253.231.211:8080    HTTPS   NOA Indonesia   new -   11-jul-2017 21:00
110.232.82.253:53695    SOCKS5  HIA Indonesia   60% (3) +   11-jul-2017 20:59
79.127.108.219:8080 HTTPS   NOA Iran, Islamic Republic of   41% (9) +   11-jul-2017 20:58
189.219.24.155:16057    SOCKS5  HIA Mexico  64% (7) +   11-jul-2017 20:58
189.218.237.10:52009    SOCKS5  HIA Mexico  64% (7) +   11-jul-2017 20:58
118.173.67.181:8080 HTTP    NOA Thailand    new +   11-jul-2017 20:55
38.123.201.17:8080  HTTPS   NOA United States   69% (25) +  11-jul-2017 20:55
81.128.165.5:3128   HTTP    ANM United Kingdom  53% (59) +  11-jul-2017 20:54
64.137.185.193:8080 HTTP    NOA Canada  new +   11-jul-2017 20:54
103.76.12.118:8080  HTTPS   NOA Indonesia   46% (75) +  11-jul-2017 20:54
209.141.47.120:80   HTTP    ANM United States   58% (97) +  11-jul-2017 20:53
109.230.100.255:9090    HTTPS   NOA Iran, Islamic Republic of   91% (135) - 11-jul-2017 20:52
180.250.174.251:8080    HTTPS   NOA Indonesia   29% (40) -  11-jul-2017 20:52
180.251.81.2:8080   HTTPS   HIA Indonesia   new +   11-jul-2017 20:51
151.80.197.192:80   HTTP    ANM France  50% (844) + 11-jul-2017 20:50
89.36.212.204:1189  HTTP    NOA France  100% (8) +  11-jul-2017 20:47
109.230.230.209:3128    HTTP    NOA Germany 100% (43) - 11-jul-2017 20:47
36.80.222.186:8080  HTTP    NOA Indonesia   new -   11-jul-2017 20:47
41.204.32.194:53281 HTTPS   HIA Ghana   58% (15) -  11-jul-2017 20:46
188.195.53.120:8080 HTTP    HIA Germany 50% (1) +   11-jul-2017 20:45
```

Comment: I tested your code and it deletes everything after the first space in each line. Can you share some examples demonstrating the behavior you say you're seeing?

Comment: [Here's a fiddle demonstrating](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Wm3r3u) that the code you provided doesn't exhibit the behavior you claim. Though personally if I were looking for an ip address with a port number at the beginning of each line, I'd use a regex. Not that it matters; your code is fine, assuming you want to preserve the space.

Comment: I should say, the code you *posted in your question* is fine. I suspect that the actual code you're having the problem with is different.

Comment: I'm also not sure if OP is asking the right questions.  OP has dissented 2/3 answers given below.

Comment: I think you need to re-phrase your question because it seems folks aren't understanding what you actually want. Perhaps post sample output based on the sample input you shared.

Comment: Those are tabs, not spaces.

Comment: @juharr Right code, wrong input. /*slaps forehead*/. My regex would still work though.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Yeah you don't see the tabs unless you actually edit the question, but the way it was lining up was what tipped me off.

Comment: Worth remembering, that the markdown will do that. If you copy it from the HTML, not the editor, you get spaces.

Answer (score 9):

It would be simpler to do a `string.Split()`:

```
string input = "some:kind of string   that I want      totrim please."; 
input = input.Split()[0];
//input = "some:kind" now
```

I even added your sample input to my fiddle and it works flawlessly, fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/PRsFVt)

Comment: No it wouldn't.. what if there were more than two spaces in the first occurrence? That string will be random.

Comment: You said you want everything **after** the first space right?  My solution gives you the 0 index so its everything before the first occurrence of any space.

Comment: @SerioskOfficial look at [my fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/PRsFVt).  Is that not the output you want?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your data the issue is that you're looking for spaces, but the values are separated by tabs.  So you need to use `IndexOf('\t')` instead.  Alternatively the solution of using `Split()[0]` would also work as that will split on any white space including tabs.

Answer (score 0):

try to use

```
lines.Add(textLine.Split(null)[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Matching with a help of *regular expresssion* is yet another way:

```
string input = "some:kind of string   that I want      totrim please."; 

// @"^\s*\S*" if you want to ignore leading spaces
input = Regex.Match(input, @"^\S*").Value;
```

which can be helpful when we want to get rid of part after *whitespace* (space, tabulation, non-breaking space etc.)