# How to remove all chars after a space in Textbox

Tags: c#, string, replace, textbox

My Problem is that my Users sometimes did mistakes and i want to avoid this by removing the splitted part of the string automatically.

i dont want to combine the splitted string, i just want to remove all what is written after the space.

Should look like this:
[image]

All what i selected should be automatically removed after i press the Button to Save/Confirm.

Comment: I'd recommend to give a validation error instead. You could end up with only a given name and empty family name, otherwise.

Comment: https://gyazo.com/0f16c8feb0edfa8710f7446922a49368 This is how my form looks like. my Users have a second textbox to write there full name correctly. but i want to avoid that they write something after a Space.

Comment: The comment before did not ask for more information, he gave you an UX advice for your issue. Don't fix yourself the input of the user, tell them that they typed something wrong in an error message and let them fix this themself to avoid other mistakes that could happen.

Comment: `string input = Regex.Match(input, @"^\S*").Value;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Source: [Removing everything after the first " " in a string? (space)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45042072/removing-everything-after-the-first-in-a-string-space)

It would be simpler to do a string.Split():

```
string input = "some:kind of string   that I want      totrim please."; 
input = input.Split()[0];
//input = "some:kind" now
```

So it should look something like this, based on what are you working on (I suppose WPF)

```
string inputText = txtInput.Text;
inputText.Split()[0];
```

Comment: If this is a copy/paste from another answer, the correct protocol is to mark the question as a duplicate.

Comment: Also, maybe add a .Trim() before the split, that way if the user inputs an empty space at the start he won't gate an empty string after the function

Comment: Just remember this wouldn't work for input of spaces before text such as ```string input = "   some:kind";```  
I'd suggest to ```.Trim()``` input first, then Split it like so ```input.Trim().Split()[0];```

Edit: I guess @RedArcCoder was faster by 25 seconds :P  Leaving my comment as I've created snippet anyways

Comment: @xdjiijii You are correct, that should be taken care of